# Add gradient to the left side of the slider in UWP C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, slider, gradient

I have a simple UWP app written in C# and a slider with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 70.

```
<StackPanel Height="45" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Spacing="20" Margin="0,395,0,0">
    <TextBlock FontSize="24">Vol:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="volumeValue" Text="{Binding ElementName=volumeSlider,Path=Value}" FontSize="24" Width="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-9,0,0,0"/>
    <Slider x:Name="volumeSlider" IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False" Width="270" Minimum="0" Maximum="70" TickFrequency="1" ValueChanged="VolumeSliderValue" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to add the gradient to the left side of the slider scale so as I move the slider for example if the value is between 0 and 25 it is green, from 30 to 45 yellow, and from 45 and above red — something like the VU meter made of LEDs on mixing consoles, but horizontal.

I have written just a few lines of C# code, I am not a developer. I tried using the ChatGPT, but it was kind of hopeless because it gave me the solutions which have colored the right side of the scale while the left was left uncolored as I moved the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It gave me the solutions which have colored the right side of the
> scale while the left was left uncolored as I moved the slider.

The left side of the slider is not colored because you did not set [the Foreground property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.foreground?view=winrt-22621). After setting this property, it can meet your needs.

```
private void VolumeSliderValue(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    SolidColorBrush yellowBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    if (volumeSlider.Value >= 0 && volumeSlider.Value < 30) 
    {
        volumeSlider.Foreground = greenBrush;
        volumeSlider.Background = greenBrush;
               
    }
    else if (volumeSlider.Value >= 30 && volumeSlider.Value < 45)
    {
        volumeSlider.Foreground = yellowBrush;
        volumeSlider.Background = yellowBrush;
    }
    else if (volumeSlider.Value >= 45 && volumeSlider.Value <= 70)
    {
        volumeSlider.Foreground = redBrush;
        volumeSlider.Background = redBrush;
    }
          
}
```